# PowerShell query for get users under Permissions level Full Control

Tags: 2016, 2019

Using PowerShell how to get users under Permissions levels Full Control,Contribute,Edit for given Site Collection and all under subsites.

Output be like this:

User name Permissionlevel SiteURL

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this which loop through all subsites in a given site collection and lists all group members, their permissions as well users whom been granted access directly to a subsite.

This does not handle domain-group as it's not possible to get the members in those groups from within SharePoint.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

# This script does not handle domain-groups.

# Sitecollection to collect permissions from
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity https://test.sp.se.deloitte.com

$results = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

# Permission masks
# 1011028719 = Contribute
# 1011030767 = Edit
# FullMask = Full Control

$permissionLevels = @('1011028719','1011030767','FullMask')

# Loop through each web in the site
foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
    
    # Collect all the groups and users with either 'Full control', 'Edit' or 'Contribute' permissions
    $permissions = $web.Permissions | Where-Object {$_.PermissionMask -in $permissionLevels} | Select-Object XML

    # If any groups/users exists
    if($permissions) {
        foreach($permissonObj in $permissions) {

           # Get the info from the XML object
           $currPermissionObject = ([xml]$permissonObj.Xml).Permission

           # If current object is a group
           if($currPermissionObject.MemberIsUser -eq $false) {

                # Get the list of users in the group
                $currUsers = ($web.SiteGroups | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $currPermissionObject.GroupName}).Users

                if($currUsers.Count -gt 0) {

                    # Loop through each user
                    foreach($user in $currUsers) {

                        # Create a new pscustomobject for each user
                        $securityObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                            "Name" = $user.UserLogin
                            "Permission" = $(
                                if($currPermissionObject.Mask -eq '1011028719') {
                                    "Contribute"
                                }
                                elseif($currPermissionObject.Mask -eq '1011030767') {
                                    "Edit"
                                }
                                else {
                                    "Full Control"
                                }
                            )
                            "Group" = $currPermissionObject.GroupName
                            "Web"  = $web.Url
                        }
                        # Add the object to the result array
                        $results.Add($securityObject)
                    }
                }    
           }
           else {

               # Create a new pscustomobject for each user
               $securityObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    "Name" = $currPermissionObject.UserLogin
                    "Permission" = $(
                        if($currPermissionObject.Mask -eq '1011028719') {
                            "Contribute"
                        }
                        elseif($currPermissionObject.Mask -eq '1011030767') {
                            "Edit"
                        }
                        else {
                            "Full Control"
                        }
                    )
                    "Group" = $false
                    "Web" = $web.Url
                }
                # Add the object to the result array
                $results.Add($securityObject)
            }
        }
    }
}
# If there is any results, export them to a CSV
if($results) {
    $results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\permissions_$($site.HostName).csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```